# Someone suggested an edit to an answer - I'd like to ask him why he thinks it's necessary

Tags: support, edits, comments, private-messaging

He put an effort to the edit (I approved a previous edit he submitted), and before I reject it I'd be happy to allow him to explain why he thinks it improves my answer. Is there a way for me to contact him and ask him via StackOverflow?

Comment: If he already made an edit you should be able to ping him in a comment. Not so sure about pending editors though.

Comment: If they have enough reputation to chat you can invite that user to a "private" chat room for you two.

Comment: You can also explain why you think it isn't an improvement in a custom 'causes harm' reject reason and say, "Please explain in a comment/chat if you still disagree".

Comment: One way you can handle it is to accept the edit, ping a message to the author via the comments, and then rollback/edit if you don't come to an agreement.

Comment: But you want to reject it... so the edit is wrong isn't it?

Comment: The issue has already been solved. The edit was accepted by two moderators, and only after it was accepted I saw his original comment which made sense. I then made a small stylistic change. I think the edit page could be improved. The user's comment should be mentioned clearly, and it would be great if there would be an option to discuss a certain edit within the edit page.

Comment: Either accept or reject the edit. There us no need to discuss it.

Answer (score -2):

You use `@<username> <message>` in the comments section under your answer. For example, if you were talking to me...

```
@JeffC I saw your suggested edit. Why do you think that would improve my answer?
```

Comment: Makes much sense. But if he hasn't commented, and his edit wasn't accepted yet, can I trust that he'd get the message? Could I just ping in this manner any StackOverFlow user?

Comment: @Ben No, [you can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020). Jeff's answer only would have worked **after** the edit was approved, so it's not really a solution for the problem in your question.

Comment: @yivi I know you posted a link that explains all of this but I have received a message through a comment from a question that I have never seen/visited. I'm not sure how that is explained. I helped a user with an answer to question #1. They wrote question #2 and then @ me from the comments under Q2 and I received the message. Granted this was probably a year or two ago so maybe things have changed since then?

Comment: @JeffC: No, that has never been the way @ pings have worked here. You cannot be pinged from question #2 unless you have posted to question #2. It's never been possible to ping a user from a question they have not participated in, and it isn't possible by design to prevent this from becoming a chat group or social networking site.

Comment: @yivi OP said "I approved a previous edit he submitted", so pinging should work, right? Not because of the pending edit, but the previous approved one.

Comment: @BenCarp You said "I approved a previous edit he submitted", the prerequisite is fulfilled, pinging should work.

Comment: @walen I had missed that. Focused on "pinging the author of a pending edit", which is the general case. On this specific case I think you are right.

Comment: @walen Yes I have, and your solution was relevant for my case. But I also wondered about the more general case. However, after his edit I have tried pinging him. when I tried @ and some characters from his name there was no autoComplete to suggest that a user would be pinged.

Comment: @BenCarp That may be because the `StackExchange.comments.tabCompleter` JS function used to show name suggestions only accounts for usernames currently visible in the `.question`, `.answer` and `.comments` sections, which would exclude users that made an edit but not the _last_ edit (as far as I could tell from the JS code). However the ping should work once the comment gets to SO servers and is parsed for user mentions.